# How to optimize the http-connection in case of Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

Want to optimize the http-connection in Blackberry(J2ME or LWUIT or RIM).

I am using the connection object this way:-
HttpConnection c=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);

I thought of using connection pool, but the problem is the url varies.

Optimize- Using the same connection object so that the code works more efficiently

Comment: What do you mean by optimize the http connection? plz brief your problem statement.

Comment: if i understand you properly have you seen this thread http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-it-possible-to-reuse-an-HTTPConnection-object/td-p/373864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connector.open doesn't work properly on the blackberry and had inherent issues in LWUIT. [CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com)'s networking layer includes special support for RIM solving networking on that device.

Comment: I am not using CodenameOne as of now....is there any other alternatives, so that I can create the connection object and keep on using for every request.(Right now creating new object for every request with the sync/async url as needed)

Comment: `Connector.open()` works well on BlackBerry. The tricky thing is the connection string that you pass to it.

Comment: But how to use it if my url keep changing but I don't want to create the object again and again and rather want to use the same object. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my application i add the requast to Queue of class Network Manager that responsible on connection in Lwuit (I can't create http connect,all done by lwuit). about optmaize you can use unsynchronizrd function that will be load the new connection on the instance only if the respone will recievd or that connection be finishe, But  i think that is "recipe" for problems.